# How do you configure a domain name for openfire server? Do I just buy a domain and set it as my XMPP domain?

Tags: server, dns, xmpp, messaging, openfire

so I am setting up a server for a messaging application which is being developed. I am using openfire server for this which I have installed and running on a PC. Right now, the xmpp domain is set to my computer name and server is working on my network, but obviously as its a local name it cannot be accessed from the outside.I am able to access the server from multiple computers on the same network using the Spark messaging client to test the server. So to be able to access my XMPP server from devices outside my network, do I just buy a domain name and set it as my XMPP domain in Openfire settings?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes, with the following caveats:

You will either have to host the DNS server yourself or have the DNS provider serve the records for you.

A domain must have a static IP to address to point to.  A home or a typical small business Internet account does not include a static IP (some providers actively prevent home accounts from serving web pages/services).

You must also configure your firewall to allow a mapping to the internal server.

I would recommend using an external provider to handle the network and hosting  services for your program.